# Return text based on ID, with one string of text taking precedence

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some product IDs. I want to be able to return the Sales status *if* there's an **active** opportunity on that product, regardless of the date of the opportunity.

**Table 1**

Product ID - Opportunity Status

1234 - Active

5678 - Active

9101 - Closed

9102 - Closed

9102 - Active

1234 - Active

**Table 2**

Product ID - Opportunity Status

1234 - ?

5678 - ?

9101 - ?

9102 - ?

As ou can see, products 1234 and 9102 appear twice. One opportunity is closed, the other is active. I want my Table 2, to return "Active" for both 1234 and 9102 since they have active opportunities in Table 1. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have a column for the date?

Comment: With that precedent, you can ignore "Closed" completely and only test for active "Active".  There are a number of ways to do this.  Personally, I would use sumproduct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had a pretty complex way of handling my "hierarchy" of opportunities, I decided to assign scores to each of my opportunities based on its type and status, and then used the following:

=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+(H29:H37=M28)*I29:I37)),J29:J37)

Where H29:H37 are order ID's in table 2, which would be compared to the order ID (M28) in Table 1, I29:I3 was the score, and J29:J37 was the Opportunity Status. I hope this helps others!